# getting 500 error nginx over https | Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

Trying to learn and understand the docker and how it works. I am trying to deploy and run an application on the docker container. Everything seems to be working as expected.

1. Nginx server is up and running.
2. Redis server is also up and running.
3. DB service seems to be working as expected.

However I am trying to enable the HTTPS on the application and as per the instructions, I am suppose to provide few details on the server environment for SSL setup which includes

```
environment:
  - VIRTUAL_HOST=mydomain.com
  - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=mydomain.com
  - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=xxx
```

When I am accessing the application dummy page (an HTML) it seems to be working as expected and I am able to open the page, however when trying to access the same page over https, I am getting 500 error. I tried to see the log file under /var folder but don't see any error in the file.

tailing the container for the logs showing me only this line:

```
nginx.1    | test.xxx.com xxx.x.xxx.xxx - - [10/Dec/2022:06:05:20 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 500 177 "https://test.xxx.com/dummy-html.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"
```

I don't see any other details. Here is my `docker-compose.yaml` file

```
version: '2'

x-logging:
  &default-logging
  logging:
    driver: json-file
    options:
      max-size: 100m

services:
  nginx:
    image: jdj/latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./srv/nginx/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./srv/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./srv/ssl_certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    <<: *default-logging
    restart: always

  letsencrypt:
    image: jdj/jrcs-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:2.0
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./srv/ssl_certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
    volumes_from:
      - nginx
    <<: *default-logging
    restart: always

  server:
    image: jdj/jdj:1.13.0
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mydomain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=mydomain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=xxx
    volumes:
      - ./jdj.conf:/jdj.conf:ro
    privileged: true
    <<: *default-logging
    restart: always

  workers:
    image: jdj/jdj:1.13.0
    command: ["./scripts/workers"]
    volumes:
      - ./jdj.conf:/jdj.conf:ro
    privileged: true
    <<: *default-logging
    restart: always

    db:
    image: postgres:13.0
    env_file: jdj.conf
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    <<: *default-logging
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:6.0
    command: [
      "bash", "-c",
      'docker-entrypoint.sh --appendonly yes --requirepass "$$REDIS_PASSWORD"'
    ]
    env_file: jdj.conf
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
    <<: *default-logging
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  redis-data:
```

I am not sure what is the issue or is there a way I can see the details on error?

Comment: Look at the server logs in the container, whatever file it logs to

Comment: @AndyRay I checked but I don't see anything..is there any specific location I should be looking at? I checked at the `/var/log` folder